# How to use setTitle since setEntry is deprecated

Tags: javascript, jquery, contextmenu, jquery-ui-contextmenu

i have an contextmenu which gets filled with an async server request.
While its loading i am prefilling this menu like this.

```
$(document).contextmenu("setEntry", "test", "(loading...)");
```

But i've seen that `setEntry` is deprecated.
So i would like to ask how do i use the recommended function `setTitle`?

If i use it like this:

`$(document).contextmenu("setTitle", "(loading...)");`

Then i get an Error.
Does someone had experience with that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct syntax is

```
$(document).contextmenu("setTitle", <cmd>, <title>);
```

in your case

```
$(document).contextmenu("setTitle", "test", "(loading...)");
```

See the [API docs](https://github.com/mar10/jquery-ui-contextmenu/wiki/ApiRef#methods) for details.